# Access - Enter Parameter Value Error on ID's colums

Tags: ms-access

I know, that some topics related with this problem are discussed on this forum, but as far as I can see main source of this error is using and comparising string values. In my case it is diffrent:
I have tables:

```
Items (ID, SID (supplier ID), Name, Price, CID (Category ID) ...)
Suppliers (ID, Name, Adress, Phone, ...)
Categories (ID, Name, ParentCategory, ...)
```

I have to mention, that all ID's are nubers, autogenerated and ID it's always Primary key, and others foreign keys.

When I want to run query like:

```
SELECT [Items].[ID], [Items].Name, [Suppliers].Name, [Categories].Name 
WHERE [Items].[SID] = [Suppliers].[ID] AND [Items].[CID] = [Categories].[ID]
```

I'm getting prompt with manual enter all ID's in Items table including main ID.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query needs a `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT [Items].[ID], [Items].Name, [Suppliers].Name, [Categories].Name 
FROM [Items], [Suppliers], [Categories]
WHERE [Items].[SID] = [Suppliers].[ID] AND [Items].[CID] = [Categories].[ID]
```